# C# How to make a repeating method in BackgroundWorker (without blocking GUI), which changes imageIndex in TreeView

Tags: c#, treeview, backgroundworker

I have simple WindowsForm application, which contains TreeView. When initializing - TreeView is building from XML with default imageIndexes. My TreeView consists of servers names. In Tag element I put Dictionary which consists of a host and IP. After the initialization I call method, wich change the imageIndex if server is timedOut. I need call this method in BackgroundWorker that non block main thread (GUI). I plan to run this method every minute. Below is this method:

```
    private void checkServersTree()
    {
        TreeNodeCollection rootNodes = treeViewSrv.Nodes;
        TreeNodeCollection childNodes;
        PingServers ps = new PingServers();
        for (int i = 0; i < rootNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            childNodes = treeViewSrv.Nodes[i].Nodes;
            treeViewSrv.Nodes[i].Text += string.Format(" ({0})", childNodes.Count);
            int downServers = 0;
            foreach (TreeNode tNode in childNodes)
            {
                if (tNode.Tag != null)
                {
                    Dictionary<string, string> dicParams = tNode.Tag as Dictionary<string, string>;

                    if (!ps.getServerStatus(dicParams["host"], dicParams["ip"]))
                    {
                        tNode.ImageIndex = 1;   //red
                        rootNodes[i].ImageIndex = 2;   //yellow
                        downServers++;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(downServers == childNodes.Count)
                rootNodes[i].ImageIndex = 4;   //fatal red
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

---

Thanks for answer!
Before I write here I read about Invoke and BeginInvoke. But I can't solve this problem - run asynchronous thread that changing TreeView ImageIndexes. I went for your link and wrote code (below), but GUI stay blocked. What am I doing wrong?

```
namespace CCCServers
{
    public partial class CCCServers : Form
    {
        public delegate void checkSrvDelegate();
        public checkSrvDelegate myDelegate;
        private Thread myThread;

        public CCCServers()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            TreeFromXML tfXML = new TreeFromXML(treeViewSrv, "../../Servers.xml");
            tfXML.initTreeNodesFromXML();

            treeViewSrv.ExpandAll();

            //checkServersTree();
            myDelegate = new checkSrvDelegate(checkServersTree);
        }

        private void checkServersTree()
        {
            TreeNodeCollection rootNodes = treeViewSrv.Nodes;
            TreeNodeCollection childNodes;
            PingServers ps = new PingServers();
            for (int i = 0; i < rootNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                childNodes = treeViewSrv.Nodes[i].Nodes;
                treeViewSrv.Nodes[i].Text += string.Format(" ({0})", childNodes.Count);
                int downServers = 0;
                foreach (TreeNode tNode in childNodes)
                {
                    if (tNode.Tag != null)
                    {
                        Dictionary<string, string> dicParams = tNode.Tag as Dictionary<string, string>;

                        if (!ps.getServerStatus(dicParams["host"], dicParams["ip"]))
                        {
                            tNode.ImageIndex = 1;   //red
                            rootNodes[i].ImageIndex = 2;   //yellow
                            downServers++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(downServers == childNodes.Count)
                    rootNodes[i].ImageIndex = 4;   //fatal red
            }
        }

        private void btnRDP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadFunction));
            myThread.Start();
        }

        private void threadFunction()
        {
            MyThreadClass myThreadClassObject = new MyThreadClass(this);
            myThreadClassObject.Run();
        }

        private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Node.Text, "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

        private void treeViewSrv_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Node.SelectedImageIndex = e.Node.ImageIndex;  //Что бы иконка не менялась при выборе узла
        }
    }

    //***************************************************************************

    public class MyThreadClass
    {
        CCCServers cccSrv;
        public MyThreadClass(CCCServers myForm)
        {
            cccSrv = myForm;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            cccSrv.Invoke(cccSrv.myDelegate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see any obvious errors. Try debugging your code. Does `checkServersTree` run?, how often?. Which thread runs this method. It needs to run on `Main` thread. And, finally, where this code is blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem. After insert on my code in special places this `Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("<<<<<<<< This is {0} thread", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));` I realized that the `Control.Invoke` is called in the main thread, and therefore all who take the time to realize not to the `Control.Invoke`. See the code below:

```
private delegate void setServersCountDelegate(int idx, int cnt);
private delegate void setChldNodeImgIndexDelegate(TreeNode tNode, int imgIdx);

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    testBuildTree();
}

private void testBuildTree()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "CheckServers";
    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("|||||||||| This is {0} thread", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
    changeImgIndex();
}

private void changeImgIndex()
{
    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("--------- This is {0} thread", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
    TreeNodeCollection rootNodes = treeViewSrv.Nodes;
    TreeNodeCollection childNodes;

    for (int i = 0; i < rootNodes.Count; i++)
    {
        childNodes = treeViewSrv.Nodes[i].Nodes;
        //treeViewSrv.Nodes[i].Text += string.Format(" ({0})", childNodes.Count);
        treeViewSrv.Invoke(new setServersCountDelegate(setServersCount), new object[] { i, childNodes.Count });
        int downServers = 0;
        foreach (TreeNode tNode in childNodes)
        {
            if (tNode.Tag != null)
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> dicParams = tNode.Tag as Dictionary<string, string>;

                if (!getServerStatus(dicParams["host"], dicParams["ip"]))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("<<<<<<<< This is {0} thread", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
                    //tNode.ImageIndex = 1;   //red
                    treeViewSrv.Invoke(new setChldNodeImgIndexDelegate(setChldNodeImgIndex), new object[] { tNode, 1 });    //red
                    //rootNodes[i].ImageIndex = 2;   //yellow
                    treeViewSrv.Invoke(new setChldNodeImgIndexDelegate(setChldNodeImgIndex), new object[] { rootNodes[i], 2 }); //yellow
                    downServers++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (downServers == childNodes.Count)
        {
            //rootNodes[i].ImageIndex = 4;   //fatal red
            treeViewSrv.Invoke(new setChldNodeImgIndexDelegate(setChldNodeImgIndex), new object[] { rootNodes[i], 4 });
        }
    }
}

private void setServersCount(int idx, int cnt)
{
    string[] spltNodeText = treeViewSrv.Nodes[idx].Text.Split(' ');
    treeViewSrv.Nodes[idx].Text = string.Format("{0} ({1})", spltNodeText[0], cnt);
}

private void setChldNodeImgIndex(TreeNode tNode, int imgIdx)
{
    tNode.ImageIndex = imgIdx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use form's [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) method to execute user interface methods on the thread that created window handles. E.g.

```
Invoke((Action) checkServersTree);
```